# One of my Bollean field is displayed as select (Unknow/Yes/no) instead of checkbox

Tags: django

I have a error I could not fix.
I have many boolean fields in a form and all arer displayed as checkbox except one that is displayed as select list

models.py

```
class Psychosocial2(Invalidite):
    """ A class to create a psychosocial 2 instance. """

    ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    ps2_res_pdr = models.BooleanField('Pas de réponse', null=True, blank=True) <- correctly displayed
    ps2_res_nap = models.BooleanField("NA", null=True, blank=True)             <- displayed as a select
```

forms.py

```
...
self.fields['ps2_res_nap'] = forms.BooleanField(label = 'NA',required=False)
...
```

template

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
{{ form.ps2_res|as_crispy_field }}
{{ form.ps2_res_pdr|as_crispy_field }}
{{ form.ps2_res_nap|as_crispy_field }} <--
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you post your entire form

Comment: my form is too long

Comment: but if i remove null=True in model for ps2_res_nap field it works but do not understand why because other booleanfield have null=True and displayed as checkbox as expected

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield), the default form widget for a boolean field is CheckboxInput, or **NullBooleanSelect if null=True**.  So it seems the 'offending' one is acting correctly, and the real question is why the others which also have null = True are not.  Is it possible you're specifying widgets for the others so that the default is not used?

Comment: No, I do not used specified widegts for other. May I precise that other boolean filed were wreated at database creation and the 'problematic boolean field' (ps2_res_nap) was added in the existing database...?

Comment: That could make sense if the other fields, when created at database creation, were somehow NOT flagged for null = True.